# Python - Single copy of List field in a class is being created across multiple instances of the class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following class. Every instance of the class that I create is having the same copy of the list field

```
class Vertex:
    label = None
    data = None
    connected_vertices_ids = []

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.label = randint(1, 100)

    def __init__(self, vertex_id, data):
        self.data = data
        self.label = vertex_id

    def print_vertex(self):
        print(self.label, self.connected_vertices_ids)
```

Usage

```
arr = []
arr.append(Vertex('Tampa', None))
arr.append(Vertex('Clearwater', None))
arr.append(Vertex('St. Pete', None))
arr.append(Vertex('Largo', None))
arr.append(Vertex('Seminole', None))
arr.append(Vertex('Orlando', None))
for vertex in arr:
    print(id(vertex), id(vertex.connected_vertices_ids))
```

Result

> 140582021542688 140582025347656
>   140582021542744 140582025347656
>   140582021542800 140582025347656
>   140582021542856 140582025347656
>   140582021542912 140582025347656
>   140582021542968 140582025347656

Comment: @depperm: it is an identifier of the *object* and is more or less the memory address where the object is stored.

Comment: You have two constructors? Is that even allowed?

Comment: You are right right it's not allowed to have multiple constructors in python. Not sure why this did not blow up then. However it was not causing the issue that I posted. I posted an answer. If you have anything to add please do.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I'm new to python and I'm not familiar with the memory model. I think fields that are initialized outside of a constructor behave as static. As soon as I changed the class code to the following, the issue was resolved

```
class Vertex:
    label = None
    data = None
    connected_vertices_ids = None

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.label = randint(1, 100)
        self.connected_vertices_ids = []

    def __init__(self, vertex_id, data):
        self.data = data
        self.label = vertex_id
        self.connected_vertices_ids = []

    def print_vertex(self):
        print(self.label, self.connected_vertices_ids)
```

If anyone could answer this question more formally, I'd appreciate

Comment: Ensure your code has correct indentation when you copy it into your posts please.

Comment: You're also correct in your reasoning. `connected_vertices_id` was declared and assigned as attributes of the `Vertex` *class*, so it was essentially a single static property being  used by all instances.